# JSOM caml query always returns undefined

Tags: caml-query, jsom

As the title says, I have a caml query that is invoked through `JSOM` code which always returns an empty collection. I am querying the list based on two columns: One being of type `User` and the other of being of type `Text`.

Here are the snipps:

```
$("#searchUser").click(function () {
    var _BizRepo = Biz.Services.SearchRepository;
    var currentCtx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var picker = SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict.clientPeoplePicker_TopSpan.GetAllUserInfo();
    var user = picker[0].Key;
    var selectedYear = $("#year").val();
    var metricsRaw = _BizRepo.GetMetricsForUser(currentCtx, user, selectedYear, "Test");

    if (metricsRaw === undefined) { //Always end up in this block
        $("#NoResults").html("No results found.");
    }
 //ommitted for brevity...
```

GetMetricsForUser() does the actual querying.

```
GetMetricsForUser: function (currentCtx, user, selectedYear, docLibName) {
            var metricsList = currentCtx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("Metrics for " + docLibName);
            var query = new SP.CamlQuery();
            query.set_viewXml("<Where><And><Eq><FieldRef Name='User' /><Value Type='User'>" + user + "</Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name='Year' /><Value Type='Text'>" + selectedYear + "</Value></Eq></And></Where>");
            var itemCollection = metricsList.getItems(query);
            currentCtx.load(itemCollection);
            currentCtx.executeQueryAsync(function () { return itemCollection; }, function (sender, args) { console.log(args.get_message()); });
        }
```

No exceptions are thrown when stepping through the code, so i'm completely lost. Am I passing an incorrect user type of object to the query perhaps?

Comment: I believe you need in your set_viewXml an opening `<View><Query>` and a closing `</Query></View>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing View and Query tags in your query. Try including `<View><Query><Where></Where></Query></View>` in your `set_ViewXml`.

Also, the preferred way of querying the user field is :

```
<Where><Eq>
   <FieldRef Name='User' LookupId='True'  />
   <Value Type='User'>Id</Value>
</Eq></Where>
```

Since it ensures that the result returned is unique.

Comment: Added in the opening and closing `<View><Query>` tags in my query and my collection is still `undefined` when stepping through. Marking this as answer since it seems to have solved my caml issue. Perhaps you could help me on my follow up question too? http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/160548/31470