# JSOM How to get User Id

Tags: javascript, client-object-model, user-accounts, jsom

When trying to resolve a user with the `ensureUser()` call, the object is always returned as `undefined` even though the user exists as a Domain and SharePoint user.

```
//Calling  code.
var currentCtx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var picker = SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict.clientPeoplePicker_TopSpan.GetAllUserInfo();
var user = _UserRepo.GetUserId(currentCtx, picker[0].Key);

//Business logic.
UserRepository: {
        GetUserId: function (currentCtx, loginName) { //loginName comes in as i:0#.w|domain\userName
            var resolveUser = currentCtx.get_web().ensureUser(loginName);
            currentCtx.load(resolveUser);
            //resolveUser is undefined after Async call and console reads
            //Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get_id' of undefined
            currentCtx.executeQueryAsync(function () { console.log(resolveUser.get_id()); return resolveUser; }, function (sender, args) { console.log(args.get_message()); });
        }
    }
```

I thought I was doing everything right according to the client OM documentation, but I guess not. How do I get the user properly?

Comment: Try hard-coding the login name as ensureUser("i:0#.w|domain\\userName")  and see if it works. Or just try removing the claims token and try with "domain\\userName"

Comment: Have you check what you are getting in 'loginName' in GetUSerId function?

Answer (score -2):

Using the below code you may get the properties such as login id, name and email id of the user currently logged in. Is this the one you are expecting?

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
$(function(){
GetCurrentUsername();
});

function GetCurrentUsername()
{
var ctxt = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
this.website = ctxt.get_web();
this.currentUser = website.get_currentUser();
ctxt.load(currentUser);
ctxt.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onSucceess), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onFail));
}

function onSucceess(sender, args)
{
alert(currentUser.get_loginName()+" ... "+currentUser.get_title()+" ... "+currentUser.get_email());
}

function onFail(sender, args)
{
alert('request failed ' + args.get_message() + '\n'+ args.get_stackTrace());
}
</script>
```